# Create a Android Library with a dependent .aar file

Tags: android, gradle

I want to create a `.aar` name X, which is also dependent on some other `.aar` name Y. When i add X to my app module which has a dependecy of Y, the build is success and apk generated contains all the files of X and Y both, works fine. Now the issue is when i look at the generated `X.aar` file it does not contain any file of Y( i know because the size of Y alone is 6MB) and the generated `X.aar` file is only 224KB. It means i am not able to wrap a another .aar file into mine.

Comment: what do you mean by this line ? Its not clear at all.. It means i am not able to wrap a another .aar file into mine

Comment: i need to create android sdk(.aar) wich is dependent on another Android SDK(.aar)

Answer (score 0):

If you add gradle dependency A to your project and it is dependent on B - your project will upload missing dependency. Are u using your own repository manager?

Comment: my app has dependency of X, and X has dependency of Y, both are local aar files

Comment: You should use local maven repository then and include     { transitive = true }   flag to your dependencies in gradle. I mean, you can't achieve wrapping one aar into another, but you can give a reference to your project where it's possible to find other dependency. Check 25.2.2 from https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: i used trnsitive=true but not working, and i dont know how to use local maven repository

Comment: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364121/Setting-Up-a-Maven-Repository check this please. And you probably need some tool like Artifactory Open Source